# Amazon alexa skill game, managing program flow

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit, dice

I am creating a simple amazon alexa game.
I have all the intents I need for the game, but my question is how do I make sure you can only choose valid options?
Example: If alexa ask me a yes or no answer how to a promt for this?
Currently: If you answer with 10 example, it will say "You just triggered NumberIntent", I want it to say "Please choose a valid option" and then repromt until it gets a yes or no.
I am currently using the canhandle on the intents but it doesn't help for the program crashing.

Would be nice if anyone can help me!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You shouldn't try to force the user to respond to a specific question.**

Vocal design is different than visual design. On a website, I can click wherever I want.

Alexa's interaction and vocal design in general is like a deck of card. Each card is an intent.
And as a user, I can choose to pick **any card whenever I want**.

As a user, I can say :

- repeat the question
- ask for help
- launch another specific intent
- or maybe I just want to quit the skill.

The card picked won't be the one you expect. It will go to either an intent you've defined or `AMAZON.FallbackIntent`

So be careful with that.
Maybe If I say something different, it's because I want to do something different.

---

If you still want to implement it on specific intent, you need to adapt the logic based on the user's progression.

- After you ask the user a question, you save the progression in the sessionAttribute

```
const sessionAttributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
sessionAttributes.progression = "EXPECT_YES_OR_NO";
```

- Within your intent, you add a logic to detect if the user should first response to yes or no

```
canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return (
      Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === "IntentRequest" &&
      Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) ===
        "MySpecificIntent"
    );
},
handle(handlerInput) {
    const { responseBuilder } = handlerInput;
    const sessionAttributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();

    if(sessionAttributes.progression === "EXPECT_YES_OR_NO") {
        const utt = "I didn't catch that, do you like StackOverflow? You can say yes or no."
        return responseBuilder.speak(utt).reprompt(utt).getResponse();
    }
},
```

I recommend you to follow alexa skill sample tutorial [zero to hero](https://github.com/alexa-samples/skill-sample-nodejs-zero-to-hero) it summarise everything you need to know about developing a skill on Alexa with examples & videos.